# How do I configure an SignalR to allow an ASP.NET MVC app to communicate with a Windows service?

Tags: c#, windows, asp.net-mvc-4, signalr

I have a SignalR hub that I would like to use to send messages from a Windows service to an ASP.NET MVC app. I am using the SqlServer backplane for this and I can see via SMSS that the tables have been created and rows are being inserted via the Windows service. The problem is that the client-side methods are not being called.

I am wondering what the problem is since I have configured both the service and the web app to use the same backplane (via a connection string). So far I have tried calling a static method on my hub (which in turn uses the hubContext to send messages to the client), which is being called as I step through the code with the debugger, but in the browser, nothing happens. I have also tried creating a hub context in the windows service itself and sending messages via the hub that way, but that doesn't work either.

Here are the relevant bits of code:
ASP.NET MVC SignalR config:

```
    public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
    {
            GlobalHost.DependencyResolver.UseSqlServer(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MyConnectionString"].ConnectionString);
            app.MapSignalR();
            GlobalHost.DependencyResolver.Register(typeof(JsonSerializer), () => s_jsonSerializerFactory.Value);
            UnitsHub.NotifyWorker.Start();
    }
```

Windows Service config:

```
public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
{
        app.UseCors(CorsOptions.AllowAll);
        GlobalHost.DependencyResolver.UseSqlServer(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MyConnectionString"].ConnectionString);
        app.MapSignalR();
}
```

Client-side methods:

```
constructor(sr: SignalR, jobId: any) {

    sr.jobsHub.client.jobStarted = this.jobStarted.bind(this);
    sr.jobsHub.client.jobCompleted = this.jobCompleted.bind(this);

    var id = 1044;
    var jId = id.toString();

    sr.jobsHub.server.trackJob(jId, true);
}

jobStarted() {
    console.log("Job started!");
}

jobCompleted() {
    console.log("job completed");
}
```

SignalR Hub method:

```
public static void JobStarted(string jobId)
    {
        var hubContext = GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<JobsHub>();
        hubContext.Clients.Group(jobId).jobStarted();
    }
```

Usage of the hub in the Windows service:

```
JobsHub.JobStarted(runningJob.Id.ToString());
```

EDIT: I've enables tracing, but it doesn't seem to provide clues as to what the issue might be. Each time the query is run against the db, it just says "No records received."

Comment: The backplane stuff exists for scalability issues, nothing else, so it's not necessary for your setup to work. The fact that you see records in Sql and you don't see calls in clients are unrelated. You might have errors in the way your clients connect to the server, did you check that?

Comment: Yes, you're right, the problem was related to the client side code connecting to the server, but it all works now.